# ng-bootstrap tabs broken on alpha.25

Tags: tabs, ng-bootstrap

I upgraded from
 @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.24"
to
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.25"
today.

Tabs stopped working. Got a template error... Thread below.

I downgraded from a saved version...started to work again.
Same error with angular 4.0.3 and 4.1.0

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined
at Object.View_NgbTabset_4.co [as updateDirectives] (NgbTabset.ngfactory.js:172)
at Object.updateDirectives (modules.js:64869)
at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64468)
at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
at execComponentViewsAction (modules.js:64729)
at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64474)
at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
```

defaultErrorLogger @ modules.js:53534
modules.js:53534 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined
    at Object.View_NgbTabset_4.co [as updateDirectives] (NgbTabset.ngfactory.js:172)
    at Object.updateDirectives (modules.js:64869)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64468)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execComponentViewsAction (modules.js:64729)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64474)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
    at Object.View_NgbTabset_4.co [as updateDirectives] (NgbTabset.ngfactory.js:172)
    at Object.updateDirectives (modules.js:64869)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64468)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execComponentViewsAction (modules.js:64729)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64474)
    at callViewAction (modules.js:64783)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (modules.js:64755)
    at checkAndUpdateView (modules.js:64469)
    at resolvePromise (modules.js:23019) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (modules.js:22990) [angular]
    at :3000/packages/modules.js?hash=f354ed55dd142a450f6d0fca572238dff1e5abf2:23067:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (modules.js:56566) [angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (modules.js:22900) []
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (modules.js:22773) []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `1.0.0-alpha.25` [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) switched completely to Angular 4 which means that you need to replace `<template>` with `<ng-template>`:

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth
      master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh
      dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum
      iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle><b>Fancy</b> title</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid.
      <p>Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table
      craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts ullamco ad vinyl
      cillum PBR. Homo nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit. Keytar helvetica VHS salvia
      yr, vero magna velit sapiente labore stumptown. Vegan fanny pack odio cillum wes anderson 8-bit, sustainable jean
      shorts beard ut DIY ethical culpa terry richardson biodiesel. Art party scenester stumptown, tumblr butcher vero
      sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Disabled" [disabled]="true">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth
      master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh
      dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum
      iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UK6LDVDduJwdS44Dmeac?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. That did it.

Comment: @user3411890 please accept the answer if it worked for you.